# Android imageView cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, imageview, android-camera, r.java-file

I am trying to access the camera in the phone and I have imported JT.bagapp.R because the R file cannot be resolved without it even though it is in the gen folder.  My code is below

```
import JT.bagapp.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class bagapp extends Activity {
ImageView iv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Button take = (Button) findViewById(R.id.take);
    take.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(requestCode == 0)
    {
        Bitmap theImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(theImage);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to import R; it's one of those things that just works when it's compiled. There may be a problem with your IDE and how it's all going together. Try restarting the IDE and refreshing your build config (if you're using Android Studio, there's a gradle refresh button in the top bar).

Comment: I have tried to restart Eclipse and that din't solve the problem.  Can you give me steps to refresh the gradle?

Comment: If you're using Eclipse and don't know how to refresh gradle, then you're probably not using Gradle. Eclipse uses Ant by default. Look up Ant-related project refresh stuff. Did you remove that import of R? That could be messing it up for you.